# Pop-up on Android

Tags: android, ios, appium, nightwatch.js

When test is running on Android/iOS I see a pop-up where I'm asked to 'Allow' or 'Block' it.
How can I handle it via 'desired capabilities'?
I tried to set in `Android`:
`"autoGrantPermissions": "true"` but it did not help me.
Also I tried to use `iOS` capabilities, as:

```
"locationServicesEnabled": true,
"locationServicesAuthorized": true,
"autoAcceptAlerts": true,
"bundleId": "io.appium.TestApp"
```

IMAGE:

[image]

Comment: Can you try for finding element id of Allow button, if it's possible to find the id/xpath then you can user click.

Comment: Permissions such as location can't be auto-granted, at least in Android

Comment: this question is for ios or Android?

Comment: Yeah, it is mostly for Android

Comment: Try printing the pages source when that popup appears. There should be an Id associated with it and then you can click on the dismiss button

Comment: This will help you out. But it has to be used after App launch. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40149521/4008376

Comment: Thanks, but you are suggesting to find element and click. But my issue is to handle this pop up via desired capabilities options only. Can it be done in such way? Thanks!